# Min and Max value in Laravel blade

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a table in my blade view and it's shown like this (i took only the tr and td part out):

```
@foreach ($event->offers as $offer)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="/offers/{{ $offer->id }}">{{ $offer->user->company }}</a></td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $offer->created_at }}</td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="btn btn-default">{{ $offer->netto }} €</span></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

What I want is to change the bootstrap btn class accordingly for min and max value but only for those 2 values!

I have found a native php function min() and max()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

But I don't know how to implement that with blade and foreach loop.

Comment: [Eloquent Collections also have min() and max() methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-max)

Comment: OK, do you know how to implement that in blade together with foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to check the min/max of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First way** is to [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortby) collection and use [the loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable). It will show min and max value only once:

```
@foreach ($event->offers->sortBy('netto') as $offer)
    ....
    <td class="text-center"><span class="btn btn-default {{ $loop->first ? 'minClass'  : '' }}{{ $loop->last ? 'maxClass'  : '' }}">{{ $offer->netto }} €</span>
@endforeach
```

**Second way** is a bit ugly, but it will show min and max **only once** even if there are multiple same minimum or maximum values. Using [`min()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-min) and [`max()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-max) helpers:

```
<?php $min = $event->offers->min('netto');
      $max = $event->offers->max('netto');
      $minShown = false;
      $maxShown = false; ?>

@foreach ($event->offers as $offer)
    ....

    {{-- Show min class only once --}}
    <?php $minClass = ''; $maxCalss = ''; ?>
    @if (!$minShown && $offer->netto == $min)
        <?php $minShown = true; $class = 'minClass' ?>
    @endif

    {{-- Show max class only once --}}
    @if (!$maxShown && $offer->netto == $max)
        <?php $maxShown = true; $class = 'maxClass' ?>
    @endif

    <span class="btn btn-default {{ $class }}">{{ $offer->netto }} €</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Just this is not clear for me....`sortBy('netto')` what is netto here? does it take the property $offer->netto or what?

Comment: Yes, it takes some property and sort collection by this property. This is description from docs: The `sortBy` method sorts the collection by the given key. The sorted collection keeps the original array keys, so in this example we'll use the values method to reset the keys to consecutively numbered indexes

Comment: It works! Just if someone would like to know sortBy() function sorts it ascending >>>

Comment: Yes it does, I thought you want to sort it from min to max, so I used `sortBy()`. But you can use `sortByDesc()` too. And glad it helped. )

Comment: for me it wasn't important how it sorts but to get the min and max netto...all works fine now, thanks to you, this is not the first time you've helped me.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

This adds additional class if the condition is met (using ternary if):

```
{{ $offer->netto == $event->offers->max('netto') ? 'ADDITIONAL CLASS' : '' }}
```

Insert it like this:

```
<td class="text-center"><span class="btn btn-default {{ $offer->netto == $event->offers->max('netto') ? 'ADDITIONAL CLASS' : '' }}">{{ $offer->netto }} €</span></td>
```

It is not the most optimized piece of code ever as it will perform [->max()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-max) on each iteration. But you can do optimizing from here on (save the max in a variable etc...). Same can be done for [->min()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-min)

**Option 2:**

Chances are you'll need something like this though. This assumes you'll change the "btn-default" class based on max/min value of netto:

```
<td class="text-center">
    <span 
        @if($offer->netto == $event->offers->max('netto'))
        class="btn btn-max">
        @elseif($offer->netto == $event->offers->min('netto'))
        class="btn btn-min">
        @else
        class="btn btn-default">
        @endif
        {{ $offer->netto }} €
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: ok you gave me an idea....what if i make 2 functions (for max and min) in my Offer model would that be better, I mean more optimized and faster?

Comment: I dont think that would be the best solution. The instance of the model won't be aware of the collection it's placed it. It basically has no way of knowing if it's min/max. One way would be to sort the offers by their 'netto' when querying (you might not want that though). Another way would be to set `$maxNetto` and `$minNetto` in controller and pass it to the view. Then check `$offer->netto == $maxNetto` in the view.

Comment: The instance of the model would be aware because the models are related and i can call $event->offers and it would return the collection...so let's try to make something of it...i mean let's try to make the best possible solution for this problem so the others can also learn.

Comment: How can we take this conversation to chat? I know when there are many comments then a link pops out, take this conversation to chat....can we do it right away?

Comment: I'm not sure. And I'll be away for next 20min ish. I'm still not sure how you would make that in a model :D But I'll be happy to see your solution. Btw if optimization is of big concern to you - make suuuure you eager load all the relationship you're calling in the view. Specifically this: `$offer->user->company` in foreach. Make sure you load your event like this: `$event = Event::with('offers.user')` or the former part will call an additional query for each offer.

Comment: I have made all the connections so that the user has an event and an event has an offer...so i can call what ever i want... just keep posting till the chat link pops out :)

Comment: This is pretty much what I suggested in 2nd comment in this thread. "One way would be to sort the offers by their 'netto' ". But I didn't post it in answer as it changes the functionality (order). Also it relies on you using Laravel 5.3, which you never mentioned and it sorts on server, rather than DB.  Anyway I'm glad you solved it